# Command for Job status history in Autosys

Tags: autosys

Can we get the status of an **autosys job**  for the past 20 days. not the `-r` command which given that particular day. the whole 20 days.

Answer (score 4):

I think -r can give you what you want. Try executing below:

```
autorep –j <your job name> -r -19
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you **AUTOHIST.cmd** Slow as heck but works from command line.

```
@echo off
SET JOB_NAME=%~1
IF [%JOB_NAME%]==[] GOTO Usage

SET NUM_ENTRIES=%~2
IF [%NUM_ENTRIES%]==[] SET NUM_ENTRIES=10
SET /A NUM_ENTRIES=%NUM_ENTRIES%-1

SET HIST_START=%~3
IF [%HIST_START%]==[] SET HIST_START=0

SET SKIP_HEADER=0

FOR /L %%R IN (%HIST_START%, 1, %NUM_ENTRIES%) DO (
  CALL :HistoricalAutoRep %%R
)
GOTO :EOF

:HistoricalAutoRep
IF [%SKIP_HEADER%]==[0] (
    SET OPTIONS="delims=" 
) ELSE (
    SET OPTIONS="skip=3 delims="
)
FOR /F %OPTIONS% %%F IN ('CALL AUTOREP -J %JOB_NAME% -r -%1') DO ECHO %%F
SET SKIP_HEADER=1
GOTO :EOF

:Usage
ECHO AUTOHIST ^<Required job name^> [Optional number of historic runs to return] [Optional number of runs back to start querying history]
GOTO :EOF
```